# error while getting response from php script

Tags: javascript, events, node.js

i have the following code in node.js

```
console.log("Sending request "+sys.inspect(request));
       var request=Yapi.request('get',config.path+'/index.php?
command='+request.command+'&'+querystring.stringify(request),config);
       request.end();
       var body=''
       request.on('response',function(response) {
               response.on('data',function(chunk) {body += chunk;});
               response.on('end',function() {
                       var rdata=JSON.parse(body);
                       if (typeof(rdata) != 'object') {
                               return proceed(false,{errno:'002',message:'Cannot parse yapi
response ('+response.responseCode+')'});
                       }
                       proceed(true,rdata);
               });
       });
```

is giving this error

```
Logging in { sessionId: '9165703144390136',
 command: 'login',
 username: 'rahul',
 password: '12345' }
sessionId=9165703144390136&command=login&username=rahul&password=12345
Sending request { sessionId: '9165703144390136',
 command: 'login',
 username: 'rahul',
 password: '12345' }

undefined:5
d":"1","id_session":"ecvgvc36d17qran917pml3t681","systemgibid":"54"}
<script la
                                                                   ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
   at Object.parse (native)
   at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/nodes/youngib/lib/
yapi.js:103:19)
   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:41:20)
   at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:112:23)
   at Client.onData [as ondata] (http.js:889:27)
   at Client._onReadable (net.js:762:27)
   at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:276:10)
   at node.js:616:9
```

Please suggest what is the problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was problem in the api call it was returnig script tag

```
undefined:5
d":"1","id_session":"ecvgvc36d17qran917pml3t681","systemgibid":"54"}
<script la
```

Answer (score 0):

An illegal token means a JavaScript property is using characters that it shouldn't, like:

```
my-var = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have line breaks in the middle of variable value and you miss some semicolons.
Try having such code instead:

```
console.log("Sending request "+sys.inspect(request));

var request = Yapi.request('get', config.path + '/index.php?command=' + request.command + '&' + querystring.stringify(request), config);
request.end();
var body='';
request.on('response', function(response) {
    response.on('data', function(chunk) { body += chunk; });
    response.on('end',function() {
        var rdata = JSON.parse(body);
        if (typeof(rdata) != 'object') {
            return proceed(false, { errno:'002', message: 'Cannot parse yapi response (' + response.responseCode + ')' });
        }
        proceed(true,rdata);
    });
);
```